# Chain query results to multiple combo boxes

Tags: c#, combobox, oledb

I have several dependent combo boxes (CB) that pull data from different tables.  It can be the selected value or a lookup value.  For example I will display text (Name) in the box, when selected, I need to lookup the corresponding int (ID) and use that value in the query to populate the next combo box.

I'm having trouble referencing the command/query results and getting a data type error. The error is:

> SQL passthru expression ... using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

**Note:** My oledb interface doesn't support ICommandWithParameters

```
// Get the ID (int) value - This works as I can convert the return value to a string and echo back to the screen
OleDbCommand tblRow2 = new OleDbCommand("select ID from Table1 where NM=  '"+ CB1.Text +"' ;" , conn3);
try
{
    conn3.Open();
    string r2 = Convert.ToString(tblRow2.ExecuteScalar());
    MessageBox.Show(r2);
    labelTableID.Text = "ID Code= " + r2;
    conn3.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex2);
}

// Pass the ID (int) value and populate the next combo box CB2
// This doesn't work and throws the data type mismatch error
OleDbCommand tblRow3 = new OleDbCommand("select STATUS from Table2 where TABLE_ID = '"+ tblRow2 +"'; ",conn3);
OleDbDataReader rdRow3;
try
{
    conn3.Open();
    rdRow3 = tblRow3.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdRow3.Read())
    {
        CB2.Items.Add(rdRow3.GetString(0));
    }
    conn3.Close();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the second set of code didn't display properly ... if confusing I can repost.

Answer (score 1):

You're surrounding your number in apostrophes, so it's being treated like a string literal.

Remove the apostrophes.

```
var tblRow3 =
    new OleDbCommand("select STATUS from Table2 where TABLE_ID = " + tblRow2 + ";", conn3);
```

Better yet, [parameterize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your query so you don't run into mistakes like this.

This is untested, but something like this should work. You can specify the name of the parameter too, but I don't think the name matters as much as the *order,* with OLEDB.

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select STATUS from Table2 where TABLE_ID = ?", conn3))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter {OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, Value = tblRow2});
}
```

Comment: +1 just for paramaterized queries. Super bad to take input from a textbox and just throw it into a database query.

Comment: I tried both = "  + tblRow2 +  ";", ...  AND ... = " + tblRow , ... (without the semicolon) ... no joy but different SQL error:  Error: SQL passthru expression contained thes errors: Syntax error, expecting one of the following .. '='
The error points to this line  rdRow3 = tblRow3.ExecuteReader();  NOTE: My oledb interface doesn't support ICommandWithParameters ... so parameters is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered most of my questions and I'm left with a logic error, i.e. my sql query doesn't return any results when it should.  Again I'm pretty new to C# so I may not have the correct nomenclature, but this is my understanding of the problem/solution.
  The OleDbCommand returns an 'object', a query can return many rows & columns, but I need a singular value for comparison in the subsequent queries ... consequently ExecuteScalar() does the trick.  Once I had a good value, I just needed to cast it in a variable (string or int) and embed properly in the next query.  So everything is 'working' (no errors), I've verified the results of each query, so I know they're correct ... but I'm not getting any results from the last command/query( tblRow3a).  Any Ideas?  Thanks @

```
                        MessageBox.Show(CB1.Text);

        string conn3str = <connection string>;
        OleDbConnection conn3 = new OleDbConnection(conn3str);

        // Get the ID (int) value
        OleDbCommand tblRow2 = new OleDbCommand();
        tblRow2.Connection = conn3;
        tblRow2.CommandText = "select ID from Table1 where NM=  ' " + CB1.Text +" ' ;" ;

        conn3.Open();

        // Convert & Pass the command result (tblRow2) to string (info only) & int (for next query) 

        string r2 = Convert.ToString(tblRow2.ExecuteScalar());
        Label_1.Text = "ID Code= " + r2;

        int r2i = Convert.ToInt32(tblRow2.ExecuteScalar());

        // Select STATUS (string) where TABLE_ID (int) = ID (int)
        OleDbCommand tblRow3 = new OleDbCommand();
        tblRow3.Connection = conn3;
        tblRow3.CommandText = "select STATUS from Table2 where TABLE_ID = " + r2i;

        // Convert and Pass command result (tblRow3) to string for next query
        // Where CODE (string) = r3 (string) 
        string r3 = Convert.ToString(tblRow3.ExecuteScalar());
        Label_2.Text = "Current Status = " + r3;

        OleDbCommand tblRow3a = new OleDbCommand();
        tblRow3a.Connection = conn3;
        tblRow3a.CommandText = "select ORDER from Table3 where CODE =  ' " + r3 + " ' ;" ;

        string r3a = Convert.ToString(tblRow3a.ExecuteScalar());
        lblInvCd.Text = "Order = " + r3a;
        MessageBox.Show(r3a);
        // Result is empty even through this same query returns results in the database
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was literally nothing, i.e. blank spaces.  
Bad: ‘ “ + var + “ ‘    Good:  ‘”+var+”’  All queries are now working properly.